# iphone, setting up application tests error _OBJC_CLASS_$_MyClass undefined symbols

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I am trying to set up application tests for my iOS application. I am using the following article as the basis of what I am doing:
http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/12/sample-iphone-application-with-complete.html

So I can created the additional targets that I need. I now have 3 targets:
-The original target
-The tests target
-The duplicate target

I have added the original target as a target dependency to my test target. I have then added the test target as a target dependency on my duplicate target.

However, whenever I try to reference any of my classes in my test cases I get:

Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MyClass", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MyApplicationTests.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AnotherClass", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MyApplicationTests.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Is there another location which I need to set up some sort of dependency to tell my Tests target that it is dependant on the original target?

Cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I found the solution to this issue at:
http://twobitlabs.com/2011/06/adding-ocunit-to-an-existing-ios-project-with-xcode-4/

You need to do the following to avoid this issue:

Go back to your app target (not the test target), set the **Symbols Hidden by Default** build setting to **NO**

Now there is no need to add any source files to the Compile Source for the test target as long as the original target is set as a dependency.

Comment: OMG after a day of trying to figure out why this was suddenly not working, this little flip fixed it.

Comment: I'm upvoting every other answer you've ever given as thanks for this!!

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the .m file for any of your classes that you reference from your test code in the list of compiled sources for your test target. From the error message you provided, that sounds like your problem. In XCode 4.2 you can add a compile source to a target by selecting your project in the project navigator, then selecting your test target, the Build Phases tab, and expanding the Compile Sources section. Click the "+" below the Compile Sources section and then select your class' .m file.

Comment: Does adding a target dependancy not do this? So does this mean that any time I add a new file to my project, I also need to update my Tests target and include that file to the Compile Sources. Seems a bit inefficient.

Comment: Yes. It's not that hard though. When you add a file to your project, in the dialog where you specify the filename, you'll see a list of the targets at the bottom. You just check the ones that apply. I think it may even save the settings from one file addition to the next.

Comment: The odd thing is that the project from the blog post that I linked above does not do this. The test cases target does not have any source files in Compile Sources other than its own test cases files and some OCMock files.

Comment: I downloaded WhereIsMyPhone-WithUnitTests.zip from that article. The LogicTests and WhereIsMyPhoneTesting targets both include class .m files from WhereIsMyPhone. Is that the project you're talking about? Not trying to be argumentative, just want to make sure I understand what you're seeing.

Comment: My original target and my duplicate target have all of the compile sources but not the actual test targets (symboled by the white box). What I am seeing in WhereIsMyPhone is that the target "ApplicationTests" does not have .m files from the actual main target such as the viewcontroller etc. It only has the .m files from OCMock and the test cases which it implements itself ( WhereIsMyIphoneAppDelegateTests.m, WhereIsMyPhoneViewControllerTests.m).